# Reachability prob ios6

Tags: iphone, ios6

In application Showing Reachability error in ios6.Can any one please help me to sort out this error in reachability ios6,PLease do the needfully.

```
@implementation Reachability
 static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info)
 {
#pragma unused (target, flags)
NSCAssert(info != NULL, @"info was NULL in ReachabilityCallback");
NSCAssert([(NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCall9back");

//We're on the main RunLoop, so an NSAutoreleasePool is not necessary, but is added defensively
// in case someon uses the Reachablity object in a different thread.


Reachability* noteObject = (Reachability*) info;
// Post a notification to notify the client that the network reachability changed.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: noteObject];


  }

 - (BOOL) startNotifier
 {
BOOL retVal = NO;
SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
if(SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context))
{
    if(SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode))
    {
        retVal = YES;
    }
}
return retVal;
  }
```

Error:

```
 Cast of C pointer type 'void *' to Objective-C pointer type 'NSObject *' requires a bridged cast
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
id objInfo = (__bridge id)info;
NSCAssert([objInfo isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was wrong class in ReachabilityCall9back");
Reachability* noteObject = (Reachability*) objInfo ;
```

Comment: `SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};` also showing the same